# CocoaPods Error When Adding New Libraries

Tags: frameworks, syntax-error, cocoapods

I am making a chat application and before I started, I installed the google Firebase frameworks through cocoapods. I now realise that I would like to use another framework to handle image caching.

However, when I add the new line to the podfile and run pod install, I get an error.

Here is my podfile

[image: ImagePod]

And here is the error:
[image]

Comment: Is that you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your add incomplete name of pod, Please correct it like this.

```
pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 3.0'
```

And then install pod againg

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing an ' at the end of 3.0
Change the line to:

```
pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 3.0'
```

Then, try again and you should be good to go.